# SignalR - Handling multiple hub connections from JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, signalr

Is there a way to handle multiple running connections to different hubs from inside a single JavaScript SignalR client?

**EDIT** I meant the ability to connect to different URLs (one can change the connection URL through `$.connection.hub.url`) from JavaScript client. It looks like it's not possible (or rather hard to do) in current implementation, as there is one global connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple hubs work against one connection and that works fine today.

Comment: Thanks! I was rather thinking about totally different urls - edited the question accordingly.

Comment: After digging deeper it looks like it's not doable ootb and would involve creating a second connection by hand in custom JS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit involved.  But since there is a .NET SignalR client, you could always connect to foreign websites' hubs from server-side code, and then route the calls back to the client either via a hub or a connection as a custom proxy object.